# Erro em expressão

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

será que alguém pode me ajudar com o seguinte erro?

[image]

Aqui abaixo está o meu código. Estou tentando corrigir esse erro, mas não obtive sucesso.

```
public IEnumerable<Dia1> GetPendenciasByUser(int centroId)
{
    var query = Db.Dia1S
        .Join(Db.Cadastros, dia1 => dia1.PatientId, cad => cad.PatientId, (dia1, cad) => new { dia1, cad })
        .Join(Db.Randomizacao, dia1 => dia1.dia1.PatientId, rand => rand.PatientId, (dia1, rand) => new { dia1, rand })
        .Where(s => s.dia1.dia1.dtd1 == null ? (Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now - s.rand.RandomizacaoData)) > 1 : (Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDateTime(s.dia1.dia1.dtd1) - s.rand.RandomizacaoData)) > 1 )
        .Select(s => s.dia1.dia1)
        .ToList();
    return query;
}
```

Comment: isso é prq o EF não sabe manipular funções que não esta em seu mapeamento ou seja... o seu (Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now - s.rand.RandomizacaoData)) ... ele não sabe converte a função  Convert.ToInt32(  para uma quey validar.... você pode ver algumas bibliotecas que ajudam a fazer isso, ou você pode tentar fazer um casting usando o (int?)(DateTime.Now - s.rand.RandomizacaoData)

Comment: Eu entendi a parte do casting, mais vc pode me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Talvez em `Functions` até role a conversão, o problema e que muitas vezes não sabemos o que precisa. isso que você fez como já foi dito não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe comando SQL para o seu Convert.ToInt32. Quando chega na etapa de traduzir sua expressão para SQL o framework não consegue traduzir um resultado, gerando esse erro. Para evitar esse tipo de problema você deve **evitar métodos de conversões ou não reconhecidos pelo framework**.

Para resolver faça o processamento da expressão antes e passe apenas o resultado dentro do seu Where:

```
var dateTimeNowAsInteger = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now);

var query = Db.Dia1S
        .Join(Db.Cadastros, dia1 => dia1.PatientId, cad => cad.PatientId, (dia1, cad) => new { dia1, cad })
        .Join(Db.Randomizacao, dia1 => dia1.dia1.PatientId, rand => rand.PatientId, (dia1, rand) => new { dia1, rand })
        .Where(s => s.dia1.dia1.dtd1 == null ? (dateTimeNowAsInteger - s.rand.RandomizacaoData) > 1 : ... )
        .Select(s => s.dia1.dia1)
        .ToList();
    return query;
```

A sua segunda expressão é bastante complexa já que você converte para DateTime e depois para int novamente, no caso você pode testar algo como:

```
(s.dia1.dia1.dtd1 - ((int)s.rand.RandomizacaoData)) > 1
```

Gostaria que testa-se já que eu não sei se ele vai respeitar a ordem de execução na expressão ou não (não possuo o compilador no momento para testar).